# Kubernetes ExternalName Services

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a Kubernetes Service with type ExternalName, I understand this service act as a proxy and redirect the request to the external service sitting outside the cluster. I am able to create the service but not able to curl it i.e I get 500 error.
I wanna understand how this ExternalName Kubernetes service work.

Comment: A 500 is a response, so you *are* able to curl it (or curl *something*, at least).  This implies that name resolution (which is essentially what an ExternalName service provides) is having some effect - otherwise you'd see "Could not resolve host" or similar.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth curl -v -H "Host: <Host>" <URL>, this is the syntax of the command I am using. Is it right? or I should add some other parameters

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Services with type `ExternalName` work as other regular services, but when you want to access to that service name, instead of returning cluster-ip of this service, it returns CNAME record with value that mentioned in `externalName:` parameter of service.

As example mentioned in [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

When you want to do `curl -v http://my-service` or `curl -v http://my-service.default.svc.cluster.local` according your namespace(in this example it is default), it will redirect you at the DNS level to `http://my.database.example.com`

I hope it was useful

Comment: If I have created my external name service in any other namespace (other than default), I am unable to use "curl -v http://my-service" to access my service. Please let me know how to make externalname independent of namespace.

Comment: @BhavaniPrasad try `curl -v my-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Does that mean the network should have a DNS set up to resolve to my.database.example.com URL, if that's the case what's the purpose of ExternalName?

Comment: To improve your answer you may want to clarify the point that this is not a 'proxying service'.
From the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname
"Accessing my-service works in the same way as other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding."

Comment: @clxoid what does redirection at DNS really mean?

Comment: @clxoid I have the same question as David He.
Could you please elaborate on the following statement
""Accessing my-service works in the same way as other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding."

Comment: DNS level means, it doesn't even care about ip behind external-name. It will just translate your request to that dns name. This is used mainly not to change service names and integrations inside of your k8s manifests even real dns changes.